# ResultSet to HashMap

Tags: java, jdbc, hashmap, resultset

I am trying to pass the output of a `ResultSet` to Java `HashMap`.

```
Map<Integer, String> sIDpNumberHashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

while (DBresult.next()) {
    int sID = DBresult.getInt("slrid");         
    String pNumber = DBresult.getString("pNumber");
    sIDpNumberHashMap.put(sID , pNumber );
    System.out.println("Output1"+ sID + "\t" + pNumber + "\n");
}
System.out.println("Output2" + "\n" + sIDpNumberHashMap);
```

While the Output1 is showing all the records(from the DB). The `put` command only takes the last value from the ResultSet in.

Output1:

```
 502332262  101E2571G103
 502332262  101E2571G103
 502332262  116E3139P001
 502332262  117E3640G025
 502332262  314B7159G003
 502332262  117E3640G025
```

Output2:

```
{502332262=117E3640G025}
```

How do I make the `put` command to iterate over the results from the `ResultSet`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your IDs are identical (502332262), and `HashMap` doesn't allow duplicate keys. That's the reason you see only one entry in the `HashMap` (containing the last value you put in the `Map`).

If you want to allow duplicates, consider a different collection to hold the data. For example, you can use an `ArrayList<SomeClass>` where `SomeClass` contains the two properties you read from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but I believe someone can get an idea from what I did.
Recently I had an almost similar challenge where I wanted to build dynamic query results (whatever select query just returns its JSON list and question would vary a lot and I can't write method per query so I had to come up with something everyone will be calling).

Below is my sample code:

```
public <T> List<T> findWithDynamicQuery(String query){
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    List<Object> mResults = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        conn = //use your connection parameters;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(out);
        return (List<T>) mResults;
    }
    try {
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = result.getMetaData();
        int column = metaData.getColumnCount();            
        while (result.next()) {
            HashMap<Object, Object> rows = new HashMap<>();
            for(int i = 1; i <= column; i++){
                rows.put(metaData.getColumnLabel(i), result.getObject(i));
            }
            mResults.add(rows);
        }
        result.close();
        return (List<T>) mResults;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(out);
    }finally{
        if(statement != null){
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
        if(conn != null){
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return (List<T>) mResults;
}
```